# ¿Cómo cargar una hoja de estilos únicamente para un gsp determinado con grails 3 y el plugin asset-pipeline-grails?

Tags: css, grails, plugin

Estoy implementando una aplicación en Grails 3.1.6, usando la versión del plugin asset-pipeline-grails 2.8.2.
Todas las vistas de la aplicación usan las mismas hojas de estilo excepto la pantalla de login, que además de las hojas de estilo que usan todas, usa la hoja de estilo "login.css".

La estructura de la carpeta assets/stylesheets es la siguiente:

[image: Estructura de la carpeta assets/stylesheets]

Mi fichero application.css es el siguiente:

```
*= require css/jquery.dataTables
*= require bootstrap
*= require css/bootstrap-theme
*= require mobile
*= require css/jquery.countdown
*= require css/layout
*= require css/nv.d3
*= require_self
*/
```

Estas hojas de estilos se cargan para todas páginas de la aplicación (incluida la de "login.gsp", ya que esta también necesita algunos estilos que hay en otras hojas) de la siguiente forma:

```
<head>
    <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
</head>
```

La hoja de estilos "login.css" sobreescribe muchos de los estilos que usan las hojas anteriores. Me interesaría que la hoja de estilos "login.css" se cargue sólo cuando se abra la vista "login.gsp". Si cargase la hoja de estilos "login.css" para el resto de vistas, los estilos saldrían de forma incorrecta. No sé si me he explicado.

He probado de cargar la hoja de estilos "login.css" en la vista "login.gsp" de la siguiente forma, pero no funciona:

```
<head>
    <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
    <asset:stylesheet href="login.css"/>
</head>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? ¿Tengo que poner de alguna manera la hoja de estilos en el "application.css" para que el estilo "login.css" se cargue sólo en la hoja "login.gsp"?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He cambiado el "href" del "login.css" por "src" y me he dado cuenta que la hoja de estilos estaba dentro de la carpeta "css"
He visto que funciona poniendo:

```
<head>
    <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
    <asset:stylesheet src="css/login.css"/>
</head>
```

en lugar de:

```
 <head>
    <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
    <asset:stylesheet href="login.css"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si cuando abres la vista login.gsp solo se necesita el estilo login.css deberías quitar los demás estilos salvo que lo que cargas en cada vista es application.css, ya que este es lo quehace es llamar a los demás estilos css, si es así entonces deberías sacar de la vista login.gsp application.css y sólo incluir login.css, si no contesté con lo que necesitabas házmelo saber para ayudarte mejor...saludos

Comment: Hola Gustavo. He editado la pregunta para hacerla más clara. Sí que necesito las hojas de estilo que hay en "application.css" para la vista "login.gsp". En el resto de vistas cargo las hojas de estilo que hay en "application.css". En resumen: Resto de vistas -> "application.css". Vista "login.gsp" -> "application.css" + "login.css". No sé qué hago mal, pero no se carga el estilo "login.css"

Comment: Prueba poner  <asset:stylesheet href="themes/login.css"/>